# XSLT error "not a node item"

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to create a nested hierarchy from a flat structure, and I am using the following key:

```
<xsl:key name="next-headings" 
              match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = 'Heading3']" 
         use="generate-id((ancestor::w:sdt[1] | 
                           preceding-sibling::w:p
                                   [w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = 'Heading1'] or 
                           preceding-sibling::w:p
                                   [w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = 'Heading2']
                               )[last()])"/>
```

I am getting the "not a node item" error, but don't understand why. Any help in translating this error is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LarsH has answered, the `or` operator has more precedence that `|` union operator, and it results in a boolean expression that you can't union to a node set.

But, besides that it looks like you want to replace the `or` operator for a `|` union, I would use this expression:

```
generate-id((ancestor::w:sdt[1] |
             preceding-sibling::w:p
                [w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val[. = 'Heading1' or . = 'Heading2']]
            )[last()])
```

**Edit**: little typo...

Comment: +1 for solving the error *and* getting at why she was using "or", thus giving a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change `or` to `|`. You meant create a nodeset via union (`|`), but the `or` operator returns a boolean value, which is "not a node item".

Comment: @Jacqueline: Besides @LarsH right answer, do check mine for a better expression.